# how to make the javascript variable the current audio clip playing

Tags: javascript

This script works: but does anyone know how I can alter the javascript so the 'var aud' on //line1 is the current audio playing -> ( i.e whichever of my 7 audio clips happens to be playing at that point), something about 'this'? Thanks

```
<script>
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio"); //line1
aud.onplay = function() { 
var aud1 = document.getElementById("myAudio1");
aud1.currentTime = 0;
aud1.pause();
};

</script>
```

Comment: You should be using a loop I guess...

Comment: setup an event listener, for when an audio is played, and then use `this` as the current audio.

Comment: N Ivanov - could you do an example please? just a learner here!

Comment: With JQuery :- `$('.audio').each(function(index, _this){if(!_this.paused) {alert(index);})})`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio"); //line1
    var audio = []
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++){                                       
        aud.onplay = function() { 
        var audio[i] = document.getElementById("myAudio"+i);
        audio[i].currentTime = 0;
        audio[i].pause();
        };
    }

</script>
```

This should work. share comment if not!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
console.log(audios)
for(var i in audios)
if(audios.hasOwnProperty(i)){
  var t = audios[i];
  t.onplay = function(){
    alert(t.innerHTML)
  }
}
```

```html
<audio controls="">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio><audio controls="">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio><audio controls="">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for all your audio elements, and then with this code it should `console.log` whichever one triggered the event. If that works then do whatever you want to do with the audio element which triggered the event.

```
var aud = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
aud.onplaying = function() {
    console.log(this);
    var playingAudio = this;
    playingAudio.pause();
}
```

Comment: @watchglass49 Remember to mark whichever answer is correct as correct :)

Comment: Thanks moidol, that looks good. Really what I am trying to do is I have 7 navigation links, when you onmouseover any of the 7 nav links an audio clip plays. However if you onmouseover several clips at once, several audio clips play at once = annoying for end user. I improved on this with an onmouseout function which stops the audioclip if you onmouseout, however what I'd really like is the first clip to finish playing unless a second clip is onmouseover'd. So on mouseover on any new audio/nav link stops all audio clips except currently playing, it's rather complicated I know!

Comment: @watchglass49 I don't think you need any onmouseout events. In the code in my answer, before you make `playingAudio = this`, you can call `playingAudio.pause()` to pause the previous clip. This allows the user to mouse over, make the clip play, and then still be able to move the mouse away and have it playing (unless he mouses over another nav link).

Comment: moidol - thanks for your advice, I think I see how it could work from your last comment yes. I will study this more and should be able to get it working, I usually get there in the end :)